# Calculate scalar potential from electric field

Tags: computational-geometry, physics

Is it possible for Mathematica to solve an equation like
$\nabla f(\mathbf{r}) = - \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ for $f(\mathbf{r})$?

I tried `Reduce[Grad[f[x,y,z],{x,y,z}]== -{ex,ey,ez}, f]`
but that does not work.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete code snippet ? Something that we could copy paste into our notebooks and see the actual error ?

Comment: What for? You need not playing with `Mathematica` for this: $$ f(\mathbf{r}) = f(\mathbf{r_0})- \int \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})  d\mathbf{r}$$

Comment: It's a differential equation so you need to use `DSolve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to combine Artes and Simon Woods comments in an answer.

Given is the electric field as
`el = {ex, ey, ez} = {er, e\[Theta], ez}` in Cartesian and Cylindrical coordinates, respectively.

Solving the differential equation can be done in Cartesian coordinates with

```
DSolve[Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == {ex, ey, ez}, 
 f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

{{f[x, y, z] -> ex x + ey y + ez z + C[1]}}
```

Or simply by integration, where one has to parametrize the integration variable

```
Integrate[{ex, ey, ez}.{x t, y t, z t}, {t, 0, Sqrt[2]}]

ex x + ey y + ez z
```

Remember the constant integration factor, which is set to zero here.

Integration is also easily done in different coordinate systems, such as cylindrical ones

```
Integrate[{er, e\[Theta], ez}.{r t, r \[Theta] t, z t}, {t, 0, 
  Sqrt[2]}]

er r + ez z + e\[Theta] r \[Theta]
```

How to use `DSolve[]` in this case I don't know yet, as

```
DSolve[Grad[f[r, \[Theta], z], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
   "Cylindrical"] == {er, e\[Theta], ez}, 
 f[r, \[Theta], z], {r, \[Theta], z}]
```

does not work.

I know this is pretty elementary, but maybe it can help others. Please help to further improve this answer!

Comment: It is about solving of a system consisting of three time-independent partial differential equations, each of the first order. As much as I know neither DSolve, not NDSolve can do this.  Please correct me if I missed something.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Works for me: `DSolve[{D[F[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}] == D[x + x y + z y + x y z, {{x, y, z}}]}, F, {x, y, z}]` (V9.0.1).  Of course the system is integrable only if the curl of the vector field is zero.