# Scalar potential function from 3D vectorial field

Tags: differential-equations, vector-calculus

I am new at this forum and a beginner with Mathematica. Today I was studying multivariable calculus and I came with this problem. For example, in 2D case I have this code:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x] == y*E^(x*y), D[f[x, y], y] == x*E^(x*y)}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

where $\vec{F}=(ye^{xy},xe^{xy})$ and if the vector field was not conservative, DSolve would return unevaluated. But, if my vector field consists of 3 variables, how can I modify my previous code?

For instance, with this vectorial field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (y^2z + 2xz^2, 2xyz, xy^2 + 2x^2z)$, I tried:

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y, z], x] == y^2 x + 2 x z^2, D[f[x, y, z], y] == 2 x y z, D[f[x, y, z], z] == x y^2 + 2 x^2 z}, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How should MMA know that yiour are looking for a vector function? Instead, try: DSolve[{D[fx[x, y, z], x] == y^2 x + 2 x z^2, 
  D[fy[x, y, z], y] == 2 x y z, 
  D[fz[x, y, z], z] == x y^2 + 2 x^2 z}, {fx, fy, fz}, {x, y, z}]

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(36897)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36897), [(100758)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100758), [(174082)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174082), [(202997)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/202997)

Answer (score 1):

There third and the first component are integrable, because

```
D[y^2 z + 2 x z^2, z] == D[x y^2 + 2 x^2 z, x]
(*  True *)
```

The mixed second derivatives are equal. You mistyped that.

Same is

```
D[y^2 z + 2 x z^2, y] == D[2 x y z, x]
(*  True *)
```

Same is

```
D[x y^2 + 2 x^2 z, y] == D[2 x y z, z]
(*  True *)
```

So this is really a vector field as a derivative of a potential.

Then work stepwise:

```
DSolve[D[f[x, y, z], x] == y^2 z + 2 x z^2, f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

(* {{f[x, y, z] -> x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + C[1][y, z]}} *)

DSolve[D[x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + g[y, z], y] == 2 x y z, g[y, z], {y, z}]
(* {{g[y, z] -> C[1][z]}}  *)
```

DSolve[D[x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + h[z], z] == x y^2 + 2 x^2 z, h[z], {z}]
(* {{h[z] -> C[1]}} *)

```
f[x,y,z]=x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + C[1]
```

Now the gradient can be applied for a check.

Same can be done with

```
DSolve[{D[fu[x, y, z], x] == y^2 z + 2 x z^2, 
  D[fu[x, y, z], y] == 2 x y z, D[fu[x, y, z], z] == x y^2 + 2 x^2 z},
  fu[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

(* {{fu[x, y, z] -> x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + C[1]}} *)

Answer (score 1):

In V12.2, `DSolve` can solve both examples in the OP:

```
DSolve[{
  D[f[x, y], x] == y*E^(x*y),
  D[f[x, y], y] == x*E^(x*y)},
 f[x, y], {x, y}]

(*  {{f[x, y] -> E^(x y) + C[1]}}  *)

DSolve[{
  D[f[x, y, z], x] == y^2 z + 2 x z^2, (* fixed typo *)
  D[f[x, y, z], y] == 2 x y z, 
  D[f[x, y, z], z] == x y^2 + 2 x^2 z}, 
 f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]

(*  {{f[x, y, z] -> x y^2 z + x^2 z^2 + C[1]}}  *)
```